# How to create case sensitive section in latex?

Tags: classicthesis

I am preparing a content using latex format, but there is a problem. The text I write for section turns into all uppercase letters.. However, in my text, I want some letters to be in uppercase and some in lowercase. how can i solve it?

Template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-template-using-the-classicthesis-package/kkbxhcwrmdgk

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,oneside]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,oneside]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcase}
\begin{document}


\section{Hello My Name is TEST}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // You may have found this code on Overleaf, while the documeentclass it uses, scrbook, is a well known standard class, found on ctan, as most packages: https://ctan.org/pkg/scrbook . Kindly have a look into its manual. Kindly search this site for scrbook and similar search terms.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you for your information. but my homework has to be written through this book. But as I said, all letters are automatically capitalized in the section. I just want to solve this. Do you have any method suggestions? I tried almost all the suggestions on the site.

Comment: Try `\let\spacedlowsmallcaps\relax` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @hair-splitter yes it worked..thank you very much

Comment: The formatting of chapter and section headings is one of the main features of package `classicthesis`. (Another *feature* of the package is to load several packages, that are not recommended while using a KOMA-Script class and therefore result in several warnings.) And because `classicthesis` loads `hyperref`, it should be loaded as late as possible.

Comment: BTW: With an up-to-date TeX Live your code results in an error message “`Package keyval Error: oneside undefined.`”, while loading package `classicthesis`. You should remove that option from `\usepackage[…,oneside]{classicthesis}`.